# To get a sum of every second digit, starting from the next to last in C

Tags: c

Im very new in the coding world, so maybe my suggestion to this function is not the best. But how I see it it should work, but it obviously doesn't. What do I do wrong?

```
//to do checksum
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 2; i <= d; i++ )
{
sum = sum + ((int) (number / pow (10, i - 1)) % 10) * 2;
number = number / 10;

}

printf("%i", sum );
```

Comment: What is the `* 2` for? Also, it looks like you combined two different methods (iterating through the digits with `pow` and iterating through the digits by dividing by ten) when you should have just picked one of them.

Comment: Yes I forgot to say that I need to multiply the every second digit by 2 (that's why I have *2). Super, I will look at it, thanks:)

Comment: If you are trying to solve [CS50x Credit (Psets1)](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2022/psets/1/credit/) please note that at [cs50.stackexchange.com](https://cs50.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bcredit%5D+checksum) you could find specific help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int sum = 0;
    int num = 4532199;
    while (num) {
        num /= 10;
        sum += num % 10;
        num /= 10;
    }
    printf("sum=%d\n", sum);
}
```

Comment: Is not something missing in the parenthesis (num) on while condition?  Should not a condition be there? like while (num > 0) for example?

Comment: if you don't put a condition on an int, then it's compared with zero. true if any number other than zero. Which is what we need. But you can write it as while (num != 0) and it would be exactly the same

Comment: @AlonaChaika Here on SO, the proper way to say "thanks" for an answer that is correct and understandable is to "accept" the answer by clicking the checkmark...